# Параметр манифеста при запуске jar файла

Tags: java, jar, linux

Прошу отнестить с пониманием, поскольку я новичок в `Java`. Пытался запустить `jar` файл в `Linux` с помощью команды

```
./java -jar /Samplejavaprogram/Sample.jar
```

и получил в результате сообщение

```
no main manifest attribute, in /Samplejavaprogram/Sample.jar
```

Подскажите, что именно надо добавить в команду (хотелось бы знать конкретный текст), чтобы выполнить `java` программу.
Привожу текст программы (может быть в нем причина)

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.*;

public class Sample {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException  {
                    int CountComputers;
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(
                    "/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/countcomputers.txt");
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            String result=br.readLine();
            CountComputers=Integer.parseInt(result);
            input.close();
            fstream.close();
            Connection con = null;
            Statement st = null;
                ResultSet rs = null;    
               String url = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.8:5432/NexentaSearch";
                String user = "postgres";
                String password = "valter89";
            ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
            try
            {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                        st = con.createStatement();
                        rs = st.executeQuery("select path from tasks order by id");
                while (rs.next()) { paths.add(rs.getString(1)); };
                PrintWriter zzz = null;
                    try
                    {
                            zzz = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/readwaysfromdatabase.txt"));
                    }
                    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
                    {
                            System.out.println("Error");
                            System.exit(0);
                    }
                    for (int i=0; i<paths.size(); i++)
                {
                    zzz.println("paths[i]=" + paths.get(i) + "\n");
                    }
                    zzz.close();

            }
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: А если это присутствует в скаченном JAR файле, а не в том, что разрабатываешь? Тогда что,
искать разраба?))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Запускаете вы правильно (если забыть про слеш в начале пути к jar; у вас что, папка `Samplejavaprogram` в корневой директории лежит?). Ошибка в манифесте jar-файла, который вы пытаетесь запустить. Скорее всего отсутствует свойство Main-Class. Проверьте, чтобы в вашей  `Sample.jar` в папке `META-INF` был файл `MANIFEST.MF`, а в нём строка `Main-Class: путь.к.вашему.главному.классу.ГлавныйКласс`.

Comment: @fori1ton а как просмотреть файл внутри `jar` на `Linux`?

Comment: в убунту в консоле набираете mc, находите свой jar файл и заходите в него как в каталог, потом находите файл внутри который хотите прочитать и F4

Comment: Стоит добавить, что манифест может быть заключен в самом .jar файле.
Если для компиляции пользуетесь Eclipse - то достаточно на последнем этапе мастера экспортирования указать майнкласс. Если компилируете простыми способами - то поищите в интернетах, я не настолько знаком с этим, но, насколько понимаю, манифест должен быть внутри папки .METAINF внутри архива.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы еще посоветовал использовать сборщик проектов, на-пример, `Gradle`.

Добавив скрипт сборки в ваш проект,  `Gradle` сделает все за Вас.

Вот пример скрипта который при сборке проекта будет паковать все в `.jar`

**build.gradle**

```
group 'MyApplication'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName ="com.common.Application"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// Include dependent libraries in archive.
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    //JSON
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20090211'

    //Log4j
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.16'
}
```